# need to save a remote files on disk using php

Tags: php, curl, save

Hi I am trying to save a file on disk using php, when I copy the address of the file in the "Location" variable it works but when I pass the value using javascript function it does not. I suppose the problem is because of whitespacing or similar issues but do not know how to solve it.

```
function upload(location){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML="done";
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","SaveFiles.php?a="+location,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

```
   if(isset($_GET["a"]))
   {
     $Location = $_GET["a"];
     FileFunc($Location);
   }

 function FileFunc($Location){

     // $Location = "http://www.xxx.com/1.jpg"; <<When I uncomment this line it works
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Location);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $myFile = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     $file = 'myFile.jpg';
     file_put_contents($file, $myFile);
 }
```

Comment: And your Javascript code is? As you mentioned this code works fine, so please post the code which doesnt

Comment: As @HankyPanky said, show as to code the fails not the one that works.

Comment: @HankyPanky, I already mentioned that javascript send the correct variable why do you guys give negative vote before thinking ?

Comment: @SaeedPirdost That's a little uninformed comment. I did not downvote. Besides, if everything is correct then which code should we look at for an answer?

Comment: @HankyPanky, I have updated the question, have a look please

Comment: Ok great, so whats the value of your javasciprt location variable? I guess you probably are passing it without full url mistakenly

Answer (score 0):

you must add server host to your curl address

```
 function FileFunc($Location){

  $Location = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$Location;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Location);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $myFile = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
    $file = 'myFile.jpg';
 file_put_contents($file, $myFile);
}
```

Comment: what the $_SERVER['http_host'] is supposed to do ? still it does not save the photo

Comment: if you have`nt any host ( for example localhost in your computer) you can not save a file by php in disk

Comment: so how come when I use $Location = "http://www.xxx.com/1.jpg"; it saves the file on the disk.

Comment: this problem is for saving

Comment: If installed PHP is in another machine you cannot directly save the file (for example in your computer) but you can use explorer to save it